# Efficient algorithm for getting the largest power of 10 which can divide an integer

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to find the largest power of 10 that can divide a given integer.

I have a simplistic implementation for now

```
int factorBase10Exp(int number){
//...
int mBase10Exp = 0;
while(number%10 == 0 && number != 0)
    {
        number /= 10; mBase10Exp++;
    }
//...
return mBase10Exp;
}
```

The expected output is

```
factorBase10Exp(3000) = 3
factorBase10Exp(333) = 0
```

I can't use std::log10 as log10(333) = 2.522, which would give incorrect results in my use case.

What can I do to make this more efficient?

Comment: do you need to make this more efficient? Is it required by someone/something? If your code runs slowly, dont expect things like this to be the bottleneck, benchmark first

Comment: You can use a binary search, but for 32 bits I find it an overkill.

Comment: You won't get anything reasonably faster for an `int`. Now you have O(bits) you can easily drop down to O( ln(bits) ) but I am not sure if constant factors wouldn't eat the difference for small numbers.

Comment: It isn't a bottleneck as the section I am putting this in is new. This could extend to int64 as well at some point.

I agree the cost isn't too high as of now. I wanted to know if there is a better implementation for this than what I have

Comment: What result is expected for 0? (You could try to make use of  2 being a factor of 10: for a number to be divisible by 10000(dec) (see Mark Ransom's answer), it got to be divisible by 10000(bin): `0 == (number & 0xF)`.)

Comment: @user940647 sorry but this seems to me like super-overkilled micro optimizatino. People shouldnt be bothered with things like these. You may squeeze a few hundred CPU cycles out of it, but it is so unsignificant that you will never, ever notice it. Unless, of course, your algorithm will run for hundreds of days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a series of divisions, each one with half as many digits as the one prior. This gives you a kind of binary search on the number of zeros.

```
if (number % 100000000 == 0)
{
    number /= 100000000;
    mBase10Exp += 8;
}
if (number % 10000 == 0)
{
    number /= 10000;
    mBase10Exp += 4;
}
if (number % 100 == 0)
{
    number /= 100;
    mBase10Exp += 2;
}
if (number % 10 == 0)
{
    number /= 10;
    mBase10Exp++;
}
```

The first division needs to be large enough to cover over half of the largest power of 10 your integer will hold.

Comment: Upvoting because the answer is clever, but still think that going from at most 9 iterations to 4 isn't worth the amount of code.

Comment: @JuanLopes: It will quite likely depend on the distribution of your input.

Comment: @JuanLopes I'm not making any judgments on the need for this code. And the same principle pops up in other contexts, it's good to know about this technique.

Comment: @MarkRansom Agree on that :)

Comment: Agreed that this is wasted effort for small numbers. If you're dealing with big integers then you should first find the largest power of 2 that divides your number by looking for the smallest set bit. Then you can use binary search to find the power of 5 (capped at the power of 2 you found earlier).

Answer (score 2):

So, you actually want to measure how many zeros are in the end of your number when written in decimal form.
If you can find an fast algorithm to convert your number to string, you can then just count zeros.